# emacs lisp how to insert-button into a temporary buffer without switching to it

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm new to Elisp. Was trying out the following code to insert clickable buttons into a temporary buffer

```
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*tmp*"
  (insert-button "My Button"))
```

It doesn't work this way, the button got created in current buffer instead of *tmp*. Then I tried modifying code to following

```
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*tmp*"
  (toggle-read-only)
  (insert-button "My Button"))
```

Unfortunately "toggle-read-only" seems only to toggle read-only for current buffer NOT *tmp*.

Is there any way I could achieve this - to insert button directly into a temporary buffer without actually switching the cursor focus to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*tmp*")
  (insert-button "My Button"))
```